# How do I script git in such a way that hooks are bypassed?

Tags: git, version-control

I am looking for an elegant way to checkout a file from a particular committish, without causing the checkout hooks to fire.

Eg, I do not want:

```
git checkout foo/bar/baz.txt
```

to result in the post-checkout hook firing.

Comment: You can disable the hook before checkout, right? Hooks are located within the `$GIT_DIR/hooks` directory of your repo.

Comment: @TanzeelKazi: Yes, but that's ugly and what if something goes wrong and they are left disabled?  Code that doesn't care about hooks has no business touching what it doesn't know about.

Comment: I did not know you wanted to do this through code. But if you do then not having checkout hooks to fire (when you already have one defined) is also ugly in my opinion. I'd rather add an exception for this file in the checkout hook script to _not_ do what it usually does.

Comment: @TanzeelKazi: So you suggest that the hooks should be somehow aware of any scripts the developer might be running?  I suggest rather, that they should be ignorant of each other.

Comment: “but that's ugly” – imo, having checkout hooks defined, and willingly bypassing them is ugly. They are there for a reason, don’t you think?

Comment: @poke: So you'd rather have your scripts run with unknown and unintentional side effects, even if the script in question is required to do something, then set everything back the way it was?

Comment: @Arafangion Why would you have scripts with *unknown* side effects set up as hooks in your local repository?

Comment: @poke: I don't know what hooks my users would want to have, but if a build system interacts with git, it shouldn't unintentionally cause side effects. And why would you have a hook *without* side effects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git show HEAD:foo/bar/baz.txt | sed -e 'some funky stuff to correct line endings' > foo/bar/baz.txt
```

Comment: I hadn't thought of that command - does it respect the locally configured end-of-line conventions?

Comment: Probably not ;) but you could sed it. Updating answer.

Comment: I don't like the sed either...  But it's the best option. Thanks!

Comment: This will leave the index out of sync with the version "checked out". `checkout` of a file updates the index _and_ the working copy.

Comment: ...obviously doesn't apply in he `HEAD` case that you've shown in your example but in the more general "from a particular committish" case, it does.

Answer (score 1):

```
git reset <commitid> foo/bar/baz.txt
git checkout-index -f foo/bar/baz.txt
```